# Codemod with jscodeshift - remove comma from import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jscodeshift, codemod

I'm trying to write a small codemod to refactor some of the code. Consider I've somethihng like this:

```js
import { mod1, mod2, mod3 } from 'package1'
import localMod from 'package2'
```

and I wanted to change this to:

```js
import { mod1, mod3 } from 'package1'
import * as mod2 from 'new-package'
import localMod from 'package2'
```

As a first step, I'm trying to remove `mod2` from the 1st line of import which I did successfully, but I'm not able to remove the comma after `mod1`.

My code snippet so far look like this:

```js
module.exports = function transformer(file, api) {
  const j = api.jscodeshift;
  const root = j(file.source);

  const reactApolloImports = root
    .find(j.ImportDeclaration)
    .filter(nodepath => nodepath.value.source.value === "package1")
    .find(j.Identifier)
    .forEach(nodepath => {
      if (nodepath.name === "imported" && nodepath.node.name === "mod2") {
        j(nodepath).remove();
      }
    });

  return root.toSource();
};
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of searching for and removing `j.Identifier` inside `j.ImportDeclaration`, find their parent nodes by `j.ImportSpecifier` expression instead. If you remove these, you should be fine.

It is more understandable, if you paste your `import { mod1, mod2, mod3 } from 'package1'` statement into [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/dcc957f7d64d6fd958ceef64c657e950/69fc83cb0767eb6a51f7eef3f505348dfd6bbc45).

[image]

Code:

```
module.exports = function transformer(file, api) {
  const j = api.jscodeshift;
  const root = j(file.source);

  const reactApolloImports = root
    .find(j.ImportDeclaration)
    .filter(impDecNodePath => impDecNodePath.value.source.value === "package1")
    .forEach(impDecNodePathFiltered => {
      j(impDecNodePathFiltered)
        // find ImportSpecifier here instead of Identifier
        .find(j.ImportSpecifier)
        .forEach(impSpecNodePath => {
          if (impSpecNodePath.node.imported.name === "mod2") {
            j(impSpecNodePath).remove();
          }
        });
    });

  return root.toSource();
};
```

Changed output:

```
import { mod1, mod3 } from 'package1';
import localMod from 'package2'
```

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) code transformer for this purpose, it make things much easier:

Here is the plugin you need, it is [Replacer](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/v18.14.0/packages/engine-runner#replacer):

```js
export const replace = () => ({
    'import {parse, compare, transform} from "putout"': `{
        import {parse, transform} from 'putout';
        import compare from '@putout/compare';
    }`,
}),
```

Also we will use a plugin [@putout/plugin-remove-nested-blocks](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/v18.14.0/packages/plugin-remove-nested-blocks) to remove additional blocks:

```js
const replaceImports = {
    report: () => '',
    replace: () => ({
        'import {parse, compare, transform} from "putout"': `{
            import {parse, transform} from 'putout';
            import compare from '@putout/compare';
        }`,
    }),
};

const source = `
    import {parse, compare, transform} from 'putout';
`;

const {code} = putout(source, {
    plugins: [
        ['replaceImports', replaceImports],
        'remove-nested-blocks',
    ],
});
```

Result will be:

```js
import {parse, transform} from 'putout';
import compare from '@putout/compare';
```

Here is how it looks with your example (with no `remove-nested-blocks` applied):

[image]

The main benefit is encapsulating work with `AST` so you can do more things faster and simpler.